# simple_html_dom to crawl entire website

Tags: parsing, simple-html-dom, web-crawler

I want to crawl an entire website. I am using Simple_html_dom for parsing but the problem is that it takes only one webpage link at a time. I want to provide only start (home page) link and it should crawl and parse all the web pages  of that website automatically. Any suggestion how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing the DOM of that single page, store all links (within the same domain) in an array. Then, at the end of parsing, check if the array isn't empty. If it isn't, take the first link and do the same.

So something like (code sample written with Python-like syntax, but you can adapt it to PHP easily - mine is rusty).

```
referenced_links = ['your_initial_page.html']

while referenced_links:  # if the array isn't empty...
    crawl_dom(referenced_links[0])
    referenced_links.pop(0)  # remove the first item in that array

def crawl_dom(url):
    # download the url, parse the DOM and append all hyperlinks to the array referenced_links
```